# How to view python object help in vscode ( e.g. help(mylist) )

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When working from the python terminal, I can get a quick definition of an objects methods.  Just enough information to easily choose the exact method I want.  How can I get the following information using vscode?  I did not paste in the entire help for the list object below but the one line definition for each of the methods is very useful.  In vscode, as I'm typing "mylist." a pop up will display giving me the available methods but I'd like to see the exact help info for each of those methods??
Thx
Al

```
>>> mylist = [1,2,3]
>>> help(mylist)
Help on list object:

class list(object)
 |  list(iterable=(), /)
 |
 |  Built-in mutable sequence.
 |
 |  If no argument is given, the constructor creates a new empty list.
 |  The argument must be an iterable if specified.
 |
 |  Methods defined here:
 |
 |  __add__(self, value, /)
 |      Return self+value.
 |
 |  __contains__(self, key, /)
 |      Return key in self.
...
...
append(self, object, /)
 |      Append object to the end of the list.
 |
 |  clear(self, /)
 |      Remove all items from list.
 |
 |  copy(self, /)
 |      Return a shallow copy of the list.
 |
 |  count(self, value, /)
 |      Return number of occurrences of value.
 |
 |  extend(self, iterable, /)
 |      Extend list by appending elements from the iterable.
 |
 |  index(self, value, start=0, stop=9223372036854775807, /)
 |      Return first index of value.
 |
 |      Raises ValueError if the value is not present.
 |
 |  insert(self, index, object, /)
 |      Insert object before index.
 |
 |  pop(self, index=-1, /)
 |      Remove and return item at index (default last).
 |
 |      Raises IndexError if list is empty or index is out of range.
 |
 |  remove(self, value, /)
 |      Remove first occurrence of value.
 |
 |      Raises ValueError if the value is not present.
 |
 |  reverse(self, /)
 |      Reverse *IN PLACE*.
 |
 |  sort(self, /, *, key=None, reverse=False)
 |      Stable sort *IN PLACE*.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install [Pylance](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance) plungin in VSCODE.

Move cursor over the object and click L-Ctrl to get help about the object.

Comment: That seems to do the trick. However, the L-Ctrl does nothing for me.. If I hover my mouse over the object it does give me info about the object.